# How to access SharePoint provider-hosted add-in via postman

Tags: sharepoint-addin, authentication, provider-hosted-app

I have created a provider-hosted add-in on SharePoint 2019 on prem. I want to access my provider hosted add-in data from postman.

I have successfully setup postman to authenticate in SharePoint, as shown below.

[image]

But when I try to access into my add-in, error 401 occurs.
I have hosted my add-in in local iis.
I am not allowed to use basic auth.

[image]

My request headers:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: On IIS → On your hosted site → Authentication → you will see the various authentication modes, what is the value Anonymous Authentication mode ? if it is disabled then you should enabled it

Comment: Yes I have enable anonymous Authentication in IIS, but still cannot get authenticated

Comment: What about the user that running Post man, is he granted the appropriate role ?

Comment: Another question, is your add-in registered in SharePoint ?

Comment: Yes my add-in is registered in SharePoint and i can access it via sharepoint, but i need to access my add-in api via sharepoint spfx web part. Yes I am running postman with the same user I am admin in SP

Comment: So if i understand well, the permissions are granted to the Add-In ?

Comment: Yes, the add-in works fine, i can access sharepoint data from my add-in. But now i want to access data from my sharepoint webpart to my add-in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140637/discussion-between-aimen-boulahia-and-nderon-hyseni).